# Yum doesnt have packages available

Tags: ubuntu, memcached, yum

I have been trying to install memcached server, I have had a lot trouble with it. Now I am following this tutorial [click](http://www.webdeveloperjuice.com/2010/01/25/10-baby-steps-to-install-memcached-server-and-access-it-with-php/) . The tutorial uses yum for installing packages e.g. "yum install libevent".
The problem is that for every package I get this error:

```
No package libevent available.
Nothing to do
```

Do I have to do some extra configuration of yum?? The only thing I have done up to now is sudo apt-get install yum.

I am using ubuntu 10.10.

Comment: Last I checked, Ubuntu uses APT, not Yum. Did you install Yum alongside APT??? If so, remove Yum and find the proper Ubuntu packages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yum is primarily a package configuration tool for Red Hat. The correct way to install the packages in Ubuntu would be to use apt-get,

```
sudo apt-get install libevent-1.4-2 memcached libmemcached-dev
```